# Can't post form value to variable in PHP (Text area)

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to write a form's content to a text file on my computer, which is from where the server is running, and I can successfully write variables that are defined like`$newVar = "Text to write.";` , but when I try to pass a value from a form in my HTML code by `$newVar = $_POST["varOutput"];` , nothing will be written in the file. My HTML form appears as so:

```
<form id="hidden"  action="submit.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="varOutput" form="hidden" rows="73" cols="100" id="varholder"></textarea>
</form>
```

I have some JavaScript that puts a string into the text area, but the string is different for each user, as they will interact with the website differently. I have tried countless times to change every little detail in my code to make it work correctly, but my efforts have been fruitless. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The PHP code is

```
$output = $_POST["varOutput"];
$fp = fopen("text1.txt","a");
$savestring = ($output . “n”);
fwrite($fp,$savestring);
fclose($fp);
```

That is the entirety of the php file that the javascript references. The "n" is to test to see if anything happens. It prints every time.

Comment: And what's your PHP file looks like?

Comment: how your form is submitted? by JavaScript? or `<input type="submit"`?

Comment: @Tun Zarni Kyaw - the form is submitted by javascript.

Comment: Is this homework or so?

Comment: No at my school we don't really have a programming class or anything similar, so I am trying to learn on my own before college.

Comment: could you show your JavaScript code also?

Answer (score 0):

Debug
1) check if the value is set in textarea.
You can use firebug or inspect hidden elements to know if value is set correctly.
2) print all posted data to on php to know if your data is posted to backend.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying different ways, I found out that I could get the $_POST to work if I used an `<input type="submit" />` element inside the form. This allowed the php variable to read the text inside the form and write it to my text file. Thanks for everyone's help, and I hope this will help someone else. Have a nice day.